# Explainer Badge

Tags: discussion

I answered and edited a question in between some hours about one day ago. As i don't have enough rep to instantly edit my edit went to review. the review was done about a hour ago. but i dont got the badge because the time of the aproving is out of the 12 hours.

is this a bug or intended? if indended - why keeping away this badge to bet get by low rep/non diament users? only usere who got this badge are two diamonds with 3.x and 109 rep....

Comment: Do you have the link to the question you suggested an edit for?

Comment: @bluefeet Oh sorry totally didn't notice your comment :/ This should be the question: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13962/how-to-retrieve-the-password-from-the-password-text-box/13965#13965